# What 90's (possibly 80's?) cartoon had a space bike in it?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This was a cartoon in the 90's (possibly a re-run from the 80's?) which featured one of the characters flying through space on a vehicle that looked like a futuristic motorcycle. The theme song/title may have included space angels or demons or something of that sort.

Comment: Can you please add some more detail? Do you know where it was shown, what channel and what language? Can you describe the characters or the bike? Can you remember any of the settings (ie where the cartoon was set) or was it just through space? Where was it made: was it eg Japanese or American?

Comment: I wish I could answer those, but I remember very little about it. It was set in space and on surface(s). The characters appeared to have been human. I don't remember if it was American or dubbed Japanese.

Comment: Can you remember any of the other characters?  That might help.

Comment: Im trying to remember one too and it may be the one your thinking of. He was on a bike and theme song was that he had a choice.. he could... or save the world. Do you know it?

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Take a look at https://old.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/d9q3dh/space_motorcycle_animes/ - it might be in that list. Also, I think one Robotech/Macross episode ended with someone trying and failing to ride a bike into space.

Comment: "Venus Wars follows a group of teenage monobike racers-turned-freedom fighters after their home of Aphrodia is occupied by the forces of Ishtar, their neighboring rival to the North."

Comment: Also, could you be confusing a scooter with a bike? Look at this pic of Doyle's scooter from *Galaxy High*: https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1350/1434417951_a5bd1f10e6_b.jpg

Comment: Pretty sure the Robotech character was https://robotech.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_Landry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's insane that 9 years later, I finally found the answer. It was *[SilverHawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilverHawks)*. I have no clue how or why I got a space bike added to the mix in my brain.

> A bionic space enforcer called Commander Stargazer recruited the SilverHawks, heroes who are "partly metal, partly real", to fight the evil Mon*Star, an escaped alien mob boss who transforms into an enormous armor-plated creature with the help of Limbo's Moonstar. Joining Mon*Star in his villainy is an intergalactic mob: the snakelike Yes-Man, the blade-armed Buzz-Saw, the "bull"-headed Mumbo-Jumbo, a weather controller called Windhammer, a shapeshifter known as Mo-Lec-U-Lar, a robotic card shark called Poker-Face, the weapons-heavy Hardware, and "the musical madness of" Melodia who uses a "keytar" that fires musical notes.
>
> Quicksilver (formerly Jonathan Quick) leads the SilverHawks, with his metal bird companion Tally-Hawk at his side. Twins Emily and Will Hart became Steelheart and Steelwill, the SilverHawks's technician and strongman respectively. Country-singing Bluegrass piloted the team's ship, the Maraj (pronounced "mirage" on the series, but given that spelling on the Kenner toy). Rounding out the group is a youngster "from the planet of the mimes", named "The Copper Kidd" and usually called "Kidd" for short, a mathematical genius who spoke in whistles and computerized tones. Their bionic bodies are covered by a full-body close-fitting metal armor that only exposes the face and an arm, the armor is equipped with a retractile protective mask, retractable under-arm wings (except Bluegrass), thrusters on their heels, and laser-weapons in their shoulders.

### Theme Song

Answer (score 5):

Could it be Ulysses 31? There's a decidedly 'mythic' feel to it (it mentions various greek gods) as well as a space motorcycle at the end piloted by the title character's son, Telemachus

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. I can't believe I missed this one though back in the days.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like [Biker Mice from Mars](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biker_Mice_from_Mars)

> Biker Mice from Mars is a science fiction action animated series created by Rick Ungar that began airing in 1993 in the United States and lasted for three seasons before it was cancelled. It follows three anthropomorphic mice motorcyclists named Throttle, Modo, and Vinnie who escape a war on their home planet Mars before arriving to defend the Earth from the evil that destroyed their homeland (the Plutarkians) and to one day return to Mars.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I believe only one of the characters had a bike. The characters were human(-like).

Answer (score 1):

He didn't have his own show, but Lobo showed up in cartoons once or twice. And in the show, he would have been "one of the characters" but not the main one, or even frequently seen. His ride looked like what would happen if Harley Davidson did some drugs and designed a motorcycle to work in outer space.

Comment: This was a full-time character.

Comment: Yeah, Lobo & his space motorcycle was in an episode or two of Superman: The Animated Series, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember characters names specifically, but I think there was a space bike or similar in *Thundercats*. Interstellar police forces used them. Remembering what I can from nearly 30 years ago, Mandora, a female law enforcement officer, crash-landed on Third Earth and is helped by Lion-O. She recurred in 2 or 3 more episodes.

Just pulled this from  Wikipedia:

> Mandora (voiced by Lynne Lipton) is an intergalactic police officer, who works in conjunction with a series of law enforcers to protect the peaceful people of the galaxy. She works in part to run the Great Penal Planet — which houses some of the galaxy’s nastiest criminals — and routinely comes to Third Earth as part of her patrols. When one of these criminals, a robotic pickpocket named Quick Pick, helps her and Lion-O against Captain Cracker, she makes him an Evil Chaser assistant. She travels on a specially equipped hoverbike called the Electro-Charger and uses a weapon called the “enzyme catalyzer” (a spray gun that uses a chemical described as "a closely guarded secret, once called soap"). After the Mutants and the Lunataks are removed from Third Earth, Mandora becomes a member of the League of Third-Earth.